# .NET: Get Resources by Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, resources, assemblies

How do I get all th resources dynamically from my current assembly? I have tried two methods, GetManifestResourceNames and GetResourceSet with no success. I am comfortable with solutions in VB.net or C#.

**First Method**

This first method only returns an array of length 1 with this value "MyNameSpace.Resources.resource". The problem is that there are more than 1 resource in this file.

```
Dim ca As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
Dim rn() As String = CurrentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

**Second Method**

```
Dim ca As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
Dim crm As New ResourceManager("", ca)
''//Dim CurrentResourceManager As New ResourceManager(_
         "MyNamespace.Resources.resources", CurrentAssembly)
''//Dim CurrentResourceManager As New ResourceManager( _
         "My.Resources", CurrentAssembly)
Dim rs As ResourceSet = CurrentResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
Dim rs As ResourceSet = crm.GetResourceSet( _
              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
```

**MissingManifestResourceException was unhandled**

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   ".resources" was correctly embedded or
>   linked into assembly "MyProgram"
>   at compile time, or that all the
>   satellite assemblies required are
>   loadable and fully signed.loadable and fully signed.

**Solution (as per Hans Passant)**

Copy the Namespace from the Resources.Designer.vb

```
<Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>  _
        Friend ReadOnly Property ResourceManager() As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager
            Get
                If Object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, Nothing) Then
                    Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyNamespace.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                    resourceMan = temp
                End If
                Return resourceMan
            End Get
        End Property
```

and place it in the code

```
Dim CurrentResourceManager As New ResourceManager( _
         "MyNamespace.Resources", CurrentAssembly)
Dim rs As ResourceSet = CurrentResourceManager.GetResourceSet( _
         CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's more than 1 resource in *MyNameSpace.Resources.resource*.  Which is the name you have to pass to ResourceManager, an empty string isn't going to work.

To see the kind of code you have to write, start a Windows Forms application and add a couple of resources to the Project + Properties, Resources tab.  In the Solution Explorer, click the "Show All Files" icon.  Open the My Project node, open the Resources.resx node and double-click the Resources.Designer.vb file.  Note the code for the ResourceManager property.

Comment: +1 on the hint of where to look for example code.  Sometimes I don't even realize it exists, and I always find it extremely useful.

Comment: Question: How come when I compile with "vbc /t:exe myfile.vb /res:myresouce1 /res:myresource2" I can get all my resources with GetManifestResourceNames but when I use the IDE they are all hidden?

Comment: Cancel that... Resgen will generate a resx file.

Comment: The IDE combines them into a single .resource, produced by Resgen.exe.  Which is the proper thing to do.  Your command line is similar to using Project + Add Existing Item and selecting a file, then setting its Build Action to "Embedded Resource".  Start another thread if you have more questions.